# Error al lanzar una app en android con movil físico

Tags: android, android-studio, git, github

He subido un proyecto a GitHub desde android studio y ahora al lanzar el proyecto me sale este error:

Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelable found in modules versionedparcelable-1.1.1-runtime (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1) and versionedparcelable-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)

*Build Gradle*

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Comment: agrega tu build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu proyecto marca clases repetidas, puedes excluir las clases repetidas, pero actualmente lo ideal es definir dentro de tu archivo `gradle.properties` lo siguiente:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Cuando estableces `android.enableJetifier=true` el plugin de Android migra automáticamente las bibliotecas de terceros existentes para usar las dependencias de AndroidX al reescribir sus archivos binarios.

Comment: He hecho los cambio que me has sugerido pero me siguen dando fallos.

Comment: Gracias. Error mío tras realizar los cambios lo único que tuve que hacer aparte era volver a importar la clases y se arreglo.

Comment: Volver a sincronizar tu build.gradle y todos sus archivos en el proyecto, excelente, saludos